# Devexpress merge 3 databases but some data are missing

Tags: vb.net, merge, devexpress, aspxgridview

i have problem in merging three databases in devexpress vb.net, my code is as follow
All the lotid are unique.

```
  ds.Tables("lotlist").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ds.Tables("lotlist").Columns("LOTID")}
    ds.Tables("comd").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ds.Tables("comd").Columns("LOTID")}
    ds.Tables("monitor").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {ds.Tables("monitor").Columns("LOTID")}


    dt.Merge(ds.Tables("lotlist"))
    dt.Merge(ds.Tables("comd"))
    dt.Merge(ds.Tables("monitor"))  

    'Dim dv As DataView = new DataView(dt)
     Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
    'dt.DefaultView.ToTable()

    dv.RowFilter = "[Cat] <> '' "

    DisplayGridx.DataSource = dv
    DisplayGridx.DataBind()
```

when i debug the code, all the data showed for dt.merge(3 datasets) but come to `Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dt)` then the merged data displayed is incompleted and some of the column value disappeared. Anyone can guide me on what is the problem with this line `Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dt)?` Thanks in advance.Anyone?

Comment: Its not quite clear to *ME* what you are asking. As for the new DataView, try using the default one: "dt.DefaultView"

Comment: basically when i use debug mode to run the code, the data for this 3 sets (dt.Merge(ds.Tables("lotlist"))
    dt.Merge(ds.Tables("comd"))
    dt.Merge(ds.Tables("monitor"))) displayed completely on the console, but when come to the dataview, columns are still there but some of the row data didnt display completely. I have tried the dt.DefaultView (edited on the post) but the outcome still the same.

Comment: "some of the row data didn't display completely". Can you explain in detail? Are entire rows missing, or is the data of a single field incomplete? Is the effect visible in debug mode aswell, or just on that gridview? (obviously you wont see any row where the column [Cat] is an empty string... just to be clear :))

Comment: all 3 dataset have the data but data of a single field incomplete after merged and the effect visible in both debug mode and gridview. Ya, i am aware of that row filter. I edit the post.

Comment: I wrote a little sample app, everything is fine there... So I guess its a merge problem? Are all Columns of the 3 tables identical? Could you post the Schema and take a look at the Columns DataType and MaxLength? The actual Data and how it looks like when its incomplete could help aswell... I would comment out the DisplayGrid lines, just to make sure the data is correct before that.